# Restrict writing to AD attributes

Tags: active-directory

I don't think this is possible but figured I'd ask regardless: if a user has full control over a user object in AD (i.e. they can seize ownership or change the ACL), is it possible to restrict them from writing to certain attributes, but retain their read access?  The ones in particular I am interested in restricting are `uidNumber` and `gidNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are per-attribute, so you can add an inheritable permission at the root of the domain (or OU) that applies to all user objects to deny write to those attributes.

Deny always takes precedence over Allow, so it should work.

Comment: Gabriel,
Thank you for your answer, my problem is that the admin has the ability to modify the ACL of the object, so they can stop inheritance from the parent container and remove the inherited ACE.  Does that make sense?  Dan

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But it would at least slow them down :) But at the end of the day, full access means you can change anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

As long as someone has full control of the object (or is a Domain Admin), they are going to ultimately be able to edit these attribute values, as well as do anything else. It seems like there is a process/trust issue here more than a technical issue that you need to solve for.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.  That's what I thought I was trying to confirm that.  I thought there might be some other place in the schema where this type of thing could be restricted, or something such as pre-save callbacks or triggers to perform additional validation or restriction.

Comment: And yes, I agree it is more of a process/trust issue than anything technical.